# Circuitikz small gaps in wires

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta, positioning}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}  
        \begin{adjustwidth}{1.5em}{0em} 
            \begin{circuitikz}
                \draw(0, 0) node[draw, minimum width = 1.25cm, minimum height = 5 cm] (buff1){};
                \draw(10, 0) node[draw, minimum width = 1.25cm, minimum height = 5 cm] (buff2){};
                \draw[very thick]($(buff1.north east)!1/3!(buff1.south east)$) coordinate(nearBuff1) to [multiwire = 4] (nearBuff1 -| buff2.west);
                \draw($(buff1.north east)!2/3!(buff1.south east)$) coordinate(nearBuff2);
                %\draw($(nearBuff2)!2/5!(nearBuff2 -| buff2.west)$) node[yshift = 0.15cm] {\footnotesize Hello};
                %\draw(nearBuff2) -- (nearBuff2 -| buff2.west);
            \end{circuitikz}
        \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

The output looks correct at a first glance:
[image]

But when I zoom in:

[image]

Can someone explain why there is a gap in multiwire, which is to the right of the slash (it may be hard to see, but it is there)? I think its is some kind of bug or typo in `circuitikz`?

By the way, here’s a snapshot of another file that uses multi wire:

[image]

This is from the pdf viewer on gmail.

Comment: There is no gap.

Comment: I mean’t to say that there is a visible break. If you run your code and zoom in, you should see it.

Comment: Could you perhaps consider asking clearer questions, refraining from adding an unnecessarily large preamble and accepting answers that solve your previous questions?

Comment: I have already edited it the code, and I feel that the my question is as clear as it can be.

Comment: Let me repeat, there is no gap. The packet `circuitikz` is not bug free, however this part of code work just fine. If you see something (what others not) it may be caused by your pdf viewer artifacts. Can you see this in printed image? BTW, `\tikzset` in your `circuitikz` image is not related to showed code ...

Comment: I actually took a snapshot of another file, the “break” is more visible. I meant to say that there is a white line when it shouldn’t be there.

Comment: Very helpful. Apart from still loading unrelated packages (where do you use, say, `pgfplots` here?) you had nothing better to do than uploading the screenshot that you got from another file that you however do not disclose here. Others are presumably supposed to come up with their own files and try many different viewers to reproduce the issue. If there is any issue, then it is a viewer issue, and there are several of those and one can't do much about them.

Comment: Off-topic: environments `center` and `adjustwidth` are are redundant in `standalone`. So, a MWE, which reproduce your image, can be: `\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document} \begin{circuitikz}
\tikzset{box/.style = {draw, minimum width=1.25cm, minimum height=5cm}}
\node (buff1) [box]    {};
\node (buff2) [box,right=8.75 of buff1]   {};
\draw[very thick]   ($(buff1.north east)!1/3!(buff1.south east)$) coordinate(aux1) to [multiwire=4] (aux1 -| buff2.west); \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\draw[very thick]   ($(buff1.north east)!1/3!(buff1.south east)$) coordinate(aux1) to [multiwire=4] (aux1 -| buff2.west) -- (aux1);`

Comment: Using that command actually worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can see this problem sometimes --- the bipoles in `circuitikz` are drawn so that the external line starts exactly at the same coordinates (with a bit of magic code that's there since the start of times and I will not touch).

Anyway, these kinds of artifacts are normally due to the viewer (especially when related to thin lines and antialiasing algorithms).  Your snippet in `okular` (which is not one the best antialiasing performer, by the way) shows no break at maximum resolution (1600%):

[image]

while at 200% there is a kind of artifact over there (antialiasing:)

[image]

The problem is that when the rendered find the actual coordinate for the pixels it will, in the end, round the number (welcome to finite precision). So sometimes you have a micro gap and sometimes you have a little superposition that results in the second type of error when antialiased.

What Zarko is doing in [their smart comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539707/circuitikz-multiwire-white-line/539772#comment1363534_539707) is to redraw the line from the left to the right, superposing it to the left-to-right one --- in this case, a very nice solution. Another possible solution is to use a line cap (but then you should make the two rectangles filled and in foreground).

Comment: +1! Thank you for nice words! I test OP "problem" and at most magnifying (even at the biggest one) didn't observe gap. At some one appear, but very, very tiny.  Its thickness seems to be depend on settings of pdf viewer (mine has 300dpi resolution, and screen resolution is 1920x1080), so I can't reproduce what OP shows. I'm convinced that this is not a bug. Well, Superman's has a sharp eyesight and can see what ordinary people don't :-).

Comment: How do I know about my resolution for my pdf viewer (e.g. TeXStudio pdf viewer, or other viewers in general)?

Comment: @Superman not easy. You should ask about the specific software. They normally query the system for the screen resolution, but many have tunable parameters for antialiasing and how to draw sub-pixel lines... It's a world in itself. (and outside the control or scope of TeX, I fear)

Comment: Hmmmm ok. Out of curiosity, which software do you use (e.g. lyx)?

Comment: I use `vim` as an editor with `vimtex` plug-in, and `okular` or `evince` as viewers (evince is better at graph antialiasing and okular is better at navigation, text and integration with `vim`). Linux OS. Never really got the idea under LyX...